# How to use HTML data attributes to return object data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I'm currently using HTML data attributes to display basic information when an element is clicked using `$(this)`. For example, I have the following HTML snippet:

```js
$('.element').on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $('#info').slideDown();

  var title = $(this).data('title');
  var desc = $(this).data('desc');
  var icon = $(this).data('icon');

  var info = $('#info');

  info.html('<div class="sub-info"><h1>' + title + '</h1><h1 class="icon">' + icon + '</h1></div><div class="side-info"><p>' + desc + '</p></div>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="element" data-title="title" data-desc="desc" data-icon="H">
```

It's working as intended but I need more information and keeping it in objects would be a lot cleaner I think. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you could put all the data in an object, then use the property names of that object in the `data` attribute to perform the lookup in the `click` event handler, something like this:

```js
var data = {
  foo: {
    title: 'title #1',
    description: 'description #1',
    icon: 'icon #1'
  },
  bar: {
    title: 'title #2',
    description: 'description #2',
    icon: 'icon #2'
  }
};

$('.element').on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  var obj = data[$(this).data('key')];
  $('#info').html('<div class="sub-info"><h1>' + obj.title + '</h1><h1 class="icon">' + obj.icon + '</h1></div><div class="side-info"><p>' + obj.description + '</p></div>').slideDown();
});
```

```css
#info {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="element" data-key="foo">Lorem</div>
<div class="element" data-key="bar">ipsum</div>

<div id="info"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Rory, this is exactly what I was thinking of. Cheers.